# Maximum Transmission Unit 802.11ah

Tags: ieee-802.11

What is the MTU of the standard 802.11ah? I didn't find anything in literature and also on the original PDF standard.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

802.11's *MSDU* (maximum payload size) is 2304 bytes. Encryption eats up another 8 bytes (WEP), 16 bytes (WPA2-CCMP), or 20 bytes (WPA2-TKIP) - so the respective MTU is 2296, 2288, or 2384 bytes.

Comment: Yes I know, but is it the same for 802.11ah? It is a standard for IoT devices. For this motivation I guess that the MTU should be less than 1500 byte. However do you have an official source where is it possible to find this information about 802.11ah and not 802.11 in general? I already seen the official standard.

Comment: All 802.11 PHY variants use the same L2 frame format and sizes. It's quite possible that the effective MTU in an installation is limited to 1500, 1492, ... due to an underlying Ethernet network and its connectivity. As always, this needs to be discovered by a node.